# Laravel + Polymer | No puedo importar html de un web components

Tags: html5, laravel-5, aplicación-web, polymer

Estoy utilizando LaravelCollective,

```
{!! Html::style('http://localhost/prueba/bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html', array('rel' => 'import')) !!}
```

En la consola del navegador me salta el siguiente error:

> (Imported resource from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked
>   from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.),

¿Como soluciono este error?, ¿Hay otra forma de importar Polymer?

Answer (score 0):

Para importar components usá urls relativas

```
{!! Html::style('../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html', array('rel' => 'import')) !!}
```